# Simple way to get the current keypress

Tags: c++, windows

I've started using SFML as my base graphics framework for a code editor I'm working on, the only thing I can't seem get completely right is keyboard input.

What I'm used to in QB64 (a language similar to Visual Basic), is to get keypresses using either the _keyhit command (which returns a virtual keycode), or the inkey$ command (which directly returns the current keypress's character). I'm looking for a similar solution in C++ (not necessarily cross-platform, possibly easily implementable along with SFML)

What I've tried as of now is to use _getch, which doesn't seem to work with the Windows framework, nor SFML, perhaps I should use some of the Windows.h routines for this purpose, but judging from what I've seen, those check for specific keypresses, not exactly what I need. The SFML framework provides "sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed", but that one also checks for a specific keypress, but not for the whole keyboard, I also tried creating an array that serves as a map from the "sf::Keyboard::Key" enum to ASCII characters, but its not convincing, furthermore, the keys seem to "stick" and the pressed key's character keeps getting read even after it has been released.

Comment: There hasn't been a "simple way" to do anything on computers since around the early 90's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SFML, it is actually quite simple. You need to use the sf::Event::KeyEvent class (or in this case, the struct).

https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/structsf_1_1Event_1_1KeyEvent.php

Though the catch is you have to get the event from something. Generally this is used from an SFML window.

```
//assuming your code is already set up for these items...
sf::Event Event;
while (window.GetEvent(Event))
{
    if (Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    {
         //to get the key code, use Event.Key.Code
         //your code
         //for example
         switch(Event.KeyEvent.Code)
         {
             case(sf::Keyboard::Key::Y):
                 //do stuff
                 break;
         }
    }
}
```

Heads up, it has been a while since I have worked with SFML so I am not 100% sure if the it will work with switch statements. Comparing with `==` will work too, in an `if-else if-else` statement.
There may also be other ways to get the `sf::Event` defined without a window. 
Otherwise, it is fairly simple.

Comment: This is assuming you're running SFML as the graphics, so this option is best for you.

Comment: Thanks, this works, however the class member seems to be called "key" instead of "KeyEvent", and "GetEvent" is called "pollEvent". Anyways, it would be great if SFML used ASCII constants instead of its own propietary constants.

Comment: Hey! I found a better solution to this, using sf::Event::TextEntered, and event.text
https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=2269.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking just to detect a keypress kbhit() is the fuction.(Borland family of compilers , conio.h , but not a part of C++ standards when I googled it ). 
https://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html

Alternative :  Under Unix-like operating system you can use ncurses to emulate most conio behavior( see if it works for you)
https://www.quora.com/With-which-function-can-I-replace-kbhit-in-C++-because-the-header-conio-h-doesnt-exist-in-linux

If you are looking for a code that can detect which key was pressed (ie Numpad 1 and 1 above the alphabets or Something like Esc or arrow keys).This code worked for me on a **borland compiler.** When you fetch the scan code ( not ascii ) it is different for every key in keyboard ( even the non ascii ones have a value)

```
void getkey()
{
union REGS ii,oo;
while(!kbhit());
ii.h.ah=0;//service no for ascii and scan code
int86(22,&ii,&oo);
ascii=oo.h.al;
scan=oo.h.ah;
}
```

I used the above code in my school project, so I don't remember the exact source where I found it  .But I think it was Let us C by Yashwant Kanetkar under the GUI part ( It was removed later so you are looking for a publication pre 2008).

Hope it helps.